# Simulating recursion as a stack return error

Tags: c++

I am redesigning the factorial recursion function program so that it simulates recursion using a stack. My function appears to be doing what it's supposed to but I can't seem to return the value of "answer" back to the main program.

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int count = n;
    int answer = 1;
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(n);
    while(count != 1)
    {
        s.push(count-1);
        count--;
    }
    while(s.top() <= n)
    {
        answer *= s.top(); //This is working
        s.pop();
    }
    cout << answer << endl; //shows no answer
    return answer; //returns nothing
}
int main()
{
    int answer = fact(5);
    cout << "answer: " << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting the answer to be 120 and to be printed out in my main, but it's not happening.

Comment: Look closely at `while(s.top() <= n)`.  When will this loop end with your code?  It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `while(s.top() <= n)` you never push anything into `s` for which this condition is false

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something stupid. I changed it to `while(!s.empty())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the termination condition of the second loop

```
while(s.top() <= n)
{
    answer *= s.top(); //This is working
    s.pop();
}
```

There is no value in `s` that is greater than `n` so you will call `top()` and `pop()` on an empty stack. This is undefined behaviour and at best will segfault.  Fixing the  conditon works fine and gives 120 as expected:

```
while (!s.empty())
{
    answer *= s.top();
    s.pop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. NathanOliver helped me see the light, and you've confirmed my correction. Much appreciated.